# Need to display data from an sql server database

Tags: android, sql-server

I making a dashboard for an android app and fetching the data from an sql server database. Clicking on a cardview displays some data that I'm fetching from the database. How can I do it automatically that it just displays on the card view without clicking on it

here is code snippet:

```
cardView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

                try {

                    String sql = "select sum(gross_profit) from stocks";
                    Connection conn = connectionBD(JTDS);
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    resultSet.next();
                    String gp = resultSet.getString(1);

                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Gross profit is" + gp, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                            .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {


                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                }
                            });

                    snackbar.show();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Error check your connection settings", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                        .setAction("DISMISS", new View.OnClickListener() {


    cardView                         @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Put the code inside `OnClickListener` outside or put it in a method and call it

Comment: alright thanks for that

Comment: Isnt that what you were looking for?

Comment: no I want it to load the data automatically and then show it on a textview in a cardview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Logically :**

**Step 1** Load the data at startup and store in a List or Hashmap with card_id(key) and some value object.

**Step 2** when preparing the cards set the value corresponding to your Card IDs.

**Thats It**